# UIButton action generates a SIGABRT but no breakpoint triggers

Tags: swift

I have this code to create a button on my storyboard

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    signupButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    ...
 }

func pressed(sender:UIButton!) {
     println("Pressed")
}
```

However, it throws a SIGABRT error when I press the button. So, I added a breakpoint on all exceptions. However, no breakpoint was ever it - it just threw the exception. How do I find out what's causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here...

**First:** You placed the `pressed` function in the scope of viewDidLoad, when it needs to be outside of that function and in the scope of the class. Move the function `pressed` out of `viewDidLoad()`.

**Second:** This is not what is causein the signal abort crash, but it is needed nonetheless. Add a semicolon to the action selector name.

```
signupButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Or, if you don't need to pass any object to the function `pressed`, then change the function header to `func pressed()`.

**BASIC EXAMPLE: (tested and working in new project)**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let signupButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100.0, 100.0))
        signupButton.setTitle("BUTTON", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        signupButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(signupButton)
    }

    func pressed(sender:UIButton!) {
        println("Button pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did both of those things but it still happens.

Comment: See my edit, the problem is that you put the `pressed` function in viewDidLoad, so the button target cannot find the function when pressed.

Comment: Did you do both? Move the `pressed:` function out of `viewDidLoad` and add the semicolon to the action selector?

Comment: Yes, my new code contains a `pressed:` and the `func pressed()` is no longer in viewDidLoad(). It still won't even break even with breakpoints breaking on all exceptions.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code that you have?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint on the first line of `pressed` (on the line `let secondViewController...`)? Perhaps that is what is now causing a crash?

Comment: I changed that code to `println("Pressed")` (updated in question). It still crashes.

Comment: Is `pressed` in the scope of your view controller? I'm going to update my answer with basic working code that should not be giving you a SIGABRT crash.